# Settings for a rigid body physics simulation when you only want the final state fast

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I've got several interwoven interacting mesh shapes, and they all kinda "jangle and bounce around" more than I'd like.  I'm only interested in their final layout/configuration.  Is there a suggested setting that would make them as **boring** and lead-like as possible?  (don't bounce, don't jitter, don't spend forever slipping all over, just kinda THUD into a pile o parts' final resting positions).

Rigid parts, non-deforming, defaults for 1kg weight, defaults for everything else, kinda "wobbles" around for much longer than I was hoping.  I'd like it to act like clay, but without the deforming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways which on their own or in combination might help with the "wobble".

**//EDIT:** For the "don't bounce, don't jitter" see at the bottom.

1. In the *Scene Properties* under *Rigid Body World* you can increase the *Substeps Per Frame* which makes the simulation more accurate (but slower and might give strange results when set too high) and/or the *Solver Iterations* (also more accurate and slower, makes constraints and object stacking more stable).
2. In the *Physics Properties* of the rigid body objects you can enable *Deactivation*. There you can set (or leave the default) values for *Linear* and *Angular Velocity* which deactivates the rigid body object if its movements or rotations fall below the given velocity in m/s.
3. Last option, again in the *Scene Properties*, under *Cache* you can decrease the *Simulation End* frame number. Let's say, you have an animation running for 250 frames. But you want the wobble to stop at frame 100, the you set *Simulation End* to 100 and nothing will be simulated after this frame, no matter how long the animation is running. Just be aware that this makes the rigid bodies immediately freeze, no matter how much they were moving before.

[image: rigid body settings]

4. To reduce bouncing and jittering you can additionally increase the *Friction* under *Surface Response* on both *Active* and *Passive* rigid bodies and on *Active* rigid bodies you have furthermore the option under *Dynamics* to increase *Damping* for *Translation* and *Rotation*.

[image: friction and damping]

Comment: I applied your suggestions, and it is better, but it is now it is creeping across the floor, which is NOT what I expected!  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281480/my-rigid-body-dynamics-is-crawling-across-the-floor-yikes

Comment: Well, it is all dependent on your specific simulation... I can only point you to the settings which can make it better or correct. Which values will give the desired result I don't know. I don't even know what rigid bodies you try to simulate since you didn't provide any screenshots in the question. Reading about "_interwoven interacting mesh shapes_" I could also imagine that you're using incorrect _Collisions_ settings (_Convex Hull_ although you should use _Mesh_ for example), but for that you should give more detailed information in your question.