# My Rigid Body Dynamics is crawling across the floor, yikes

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

When I interlink a few rigid shapes, they don't seem to be able to "settle."  I'd like them to act like wood or non-springy metal, and just kinda drop and "thud" into place.  But no matter what I do to the friction or the angular momentum decay, it keeps thrashing and scooting around the floor.

Unavoidable side effect of this kind of physics sim?

Rigid Body World:

- Speed: 1.0
- Substeps: 50
- Solver Iterations: 50

Each Ring:

- Type: Active
- Mass: 1kg
- Shape: Mesh
- Source: Deform
- Friction: 0.5
- Bouncy: 0.0

[image: 7 interlinked torus scooting over the ground]

Comment: I would suggest that you include more information -- like either a copy of your blend file or screen-caps of setting for the active and passive objects.  What are the surface responses for each?  Try upping the Friction.

Comment: @james_t I tried upping the friction for the floor, and it still looks very alive: Settles, looks ok, then SPROING, bounces back into motion.

Comment: Like james_t said, it would help if you could share the file, also I think the problem is not always fixable and what you could do is bake the keyframes and remove the last frames so that it stops shaking